# PHP: is class property/constant value from sub or parent class

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to find out whether class property value is from parent or subclass.

```
class A {
   public static $property1 = "X";
   public static $property2 = "Y"; 

   public static isFrom($propertyName) {
      /// what should be here?
   }  
}

class B extends A {
   public static $property1 = "Z";
}

class C extends B {
}

C::isFrom("property1"); /// should return "CLASS B";
C::isFrom("property2"); /// should return "CLASS A";
```

Same question about class constants.

Is it possible to find out exact class where constant is declared (accessing subclass C)? Function defined("C::SomeConstant"); returns true if SomeConstant is declared in A or B or C. I'am looking for solution to find out whether constant is declared in class C not in parents.

Comment: You'll probably need to use reflection to accomplish this.  But it seems like poor design if you need to do this in a real application.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve a part of your question. The condition for this code to work well is in the sub-class, the redefine variable must have the different default value from the parent class.

```
/**
 * @author Bang Dao
 * @copyright 2012
 */

class A {
   public static $property1 = "X";
   public static $property2 = "Y"; 

    public static function isFrom($propertyName) {
        $class = get_called_class();
        $vars = array();
        do{
            $_vars = get_class_vars($class);
            $vars[$class] = $_vars; //for other used
            $class = get_parent_class($class);
        } while($class);

        $vars = array_reverse($vars);
        $class = -1;
        foreach($vars as $k => $_vars){
            if(isset($_vars[$propertyName])){
                if($class == -1)
                    $class = $k;
                else{
                    if($_vars[$propertyName] !== $vars[$class][$propertyName])
                        $class = $k;
                }
            }
        }

        return $class;
    }  
}

class B extends A {
   public static $property1 = "Z";
}

class C extends B {
}

echo C::isFrom("property1"); /// should return "CLASS B";
echo '<br />';
echo C::isFrom("property2"); /// should return "CLASS A";
```